# Why do people say "finite temperature" instead of "nonzero/positive temperature"?

Tags: temperature, terminology

This question is about terminology.  The term "finite temperature" is often used to mean positive temperature, or equivalently finite inverse temperature $\beta = 1/T$.  It seems to me that better choices would be "nonzero temperature" or "positive temperature" or even "finite inverse temperature".  But "finite temperature" seems to be the most common one.

Am I missing something?  Or is this one of those cases like "literally" where a word evolves to sometimes mean its opposite?

Comment: Related: [Does "finite" include zero?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186257/)

Comment: The term finite is frequently (ab)used to mean greater than zero and less than infinity. Strictly speaking this is wrong because finite just means not infinite and therefore zero is a finite number as well. However the habit is so ingrained that I suspect the abuse of the terminology is here to stay. It's normally clear from the context what is meant.

Comment: People often have in mind not the actual value of temperature, but the associated approximations. E.g., one jokes that "Zero temperature is always higher than the Kondo temperature".

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively natural use of language, and people do use it a lot. There is no such thing as true zero temperature in a physical system (partly because of the third law of thermodynamics, and partly because $T=0$ statistical mechanics only makes sense as a $T\to 0$ limit), so when you talk about zero temperature you are really using the limits $T\to 0$ and $\beta\to\infty$. When people talk about finite temperature, it is temperatures which are "finitely small".

Some people are annoyed by this (as in e.g. [this comment thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sagAC.png)), but I find it mostly harmless as it is always clear from the context what the term means.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of finite is a bound and non-zero number.

Comment: This definition is at odds with common usage, so it is not particularly useful.

Comment: @Emilio This is what thefreedictionary.com says about 'finite': in mathematics 
a.  Being neither infinite nor infinitesimal.

b.  Having a positive or negative numerical value; not zero.

c.  Possible to reach or exceed by counting. Used of a number.

d.  Having a limited number of elements. Used of a set.