# Slang: "finite value" meaning non-vanishing. Historical reasons behind this

Tags: terminology, history

Is any way to sort out the disciplines of physics where one understands under "finite value" a value that cannot be zero?

Is any historical justification for this contradictory terminology?

Comment: I think in many occurrences it is just a short for "finite value different than zero". If are more formal than I am, you might look https://math.stackexchange.com/q/710573/.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186257/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287193/2451 and links therein.